# The 'DbProviderFactories' section can only appear once per config file when running SQL Server 2012 Import Export 64

Tags: sql, import, 64-bit, sql-server-2012

I fixed this in the `machine.config` files of both .net frameworks but I'm still getting the same error, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you open SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio), then open Task Manager you'll notice even if your windows server is 2012 and 64 bit, and your SQL installation is 64 bit, SSMS is a 32bit application. 
You most likely did what did and updated the machine.config in the following directory which is for the 64bit .NET Framework:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

you should also update the 32bit framework config:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config

Fixing the first will fix SSIS packages running as scheduled jobs which may be using an ADO.NET connection because at that point SQL Agent is running it in a 64bit setting, but running the package through the import export wizard will run in 32bit mode. I also experienced the same error when selecting Edit Top 200 rows through the object explorer.